# Import Outlook 2007 messages to Outlook Express

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, import, export, outlook-express

Is it possible to import Outlook 2007 messages into Outlook Express? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/using/howto/oe/importing.mspx

Not sure if you have to export them from outlook first, or what container you would require, but it seems to suggest its possible.